# Appending to the end of line while specific occurrence of a pattern is matched

Tags: shell, awk, sed

File1:

```
abcxyz 
b 
abcxyz 
abcxyz 
b 
c
```

OutputFile:

```
abcxyz 
b 
abcxyz someValueAddedHere 
abcxyz 
b 
c
```

`sed '/^abcxyz/ s/$/ someValueAddedHere/2' File1`

Above command doesn't work for a specific occurrence, works well with all occurrences. Need to work on specified occurrence.

Thank you for the edit, Good day Sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following `awk` may help you on same. I am considering that you need the 2nd occurrence of `abcxyz` in Input_file where you need to insert the string. You could change the number of occurrences in code too.

```
awk '/abcxyz/{count++} /abcxyz/ && count==2{print $0,"someValueAddedHere";next} 1'  Input_file
```

In case you need to save the output into Input_file itself then append `> tmp_file && mv tmp_file Input_file` to above code too.

Comment: Thank you for your help , Sir. Worked as smooth as butter.                     Any idea why the sed is not able to achieve the same solution ?

Answer (score 1):

sed is for doing `s/old/new/`, **that is all**. The sed constructs to do anything else became obsolete in the mid-1980s when awk was invented and are used today just for the mental exercise, not for real solutions to problems, since an awk equivalent will always be some combination of more efficient, more portable, more robust, simpler and clearer.

```
$ awk '/abcxyz/ && (++c == 2){$0 = $0 " someValueAddedHere"} 1' file
abcxyz
b
abcxyz  someValueAddedHere
abcxyz
b
c
```

Answer (score 0):

with sed for the mental exercise

```
sed '
  /^abcxyz/!b
 :A
  $b
  N
  /\nabcxyz/!bA
  s/$/ someValueAddedHere/
 :B
  n
  bB
' File1
```

Or with gnu sed

```
sed -z 's/\(\nabcxyz\)/& someValueAddedHere/' File1
```